# how to make the div autohide when click other button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cakephp-2.0

**hai im working with show/hide slider with div..evrything is working fine with my coding..
but i want my div or my content will auto hide when i click another button(image in my coding)..**

i hope that anybody can help me with this..thanks in advance..

this is my html

```
<div id="slidingDiv">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv11">
        <img src="../img/choose/mens.png">
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv12">
        <img src="../img/choose/womens.png">
    </a>
    <div id="slidingDiv11">
        <img src="../img/choose/clothings.png"><br><br>
        <img src="../img/choose/shoes.png"><br><br>
        <img src="../img/choose/bags.png"><br><br>
        <img src="../img/choose/accessories.png">
    </div>
    <div id="slidingDiv12">
        <img src="../img/choose/clothings.png"><br><br>
        <img src="../img/choose/shoes.png"><br><br>
        <img src="../img/choose/bags.png"><br><br>
        <img src="../img/choose/accessories.png">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slidingDiv1">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv16">
        <img src="../img/choose/book.png">
    <a>
    <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv17">
        <img src="../img/choose/textbooks.png">
    </a>

    <div id="slidingDiv16">
        <img src="../img/choose/books1.png">
        <img src="../img/choose/books1.png">
        <img src="../img/choose/books1.png">
    </div>
    <div id="slidingDiv17">
        <img src="../img/choose/textbooks1.png">
        <img src="../img/choose/textbooks1.png">
        <img src="../img/choose/textbooks1.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my css

```
#slidingDiv, #slidingDiv1, #slidingDiv2, #slidingDiv3, #slidingDiv4, #slidingDiv5, #slidingDiv6, #slidingDiv7, #slidingDiv8, #slidingDiv9, #slidingDiv10, #slidingDiv11, #slidingDiv12, #slidingDiv13, #slidingDiv14, #slidingDiv15, #slidingDiv16, #slidingDiv17 {
    height:300px;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px;
    display:none;
}
```

this is my js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show_hide').showHide({
        speed: 1000, // speed you want the toggle to happen 
        easing: '', // the animation effect you want. Remove this line if you dont want an effect and if you haven't included jQuery UI
        changeText: 0, // if you dont want the button text to change, set this to 0
        showText: 'View', // the button text to show when a div is closed
        hideText: 'Close' // the button text to show when a div is open
    });
});

(function ($) {
    $.fn.showHide = function (options) {

        //default vars for the plugin
        var defaults = {
            speed: 1000,
            easing: '',
            changeText: 0,
            showText: 'Show',
            hideText: 'Hide'

        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $(this).click(function () {

            $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);
            // this var stores which button you've clicked
            var toggleClick = $(this);
            // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
            var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
            // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
            $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function () {
                // this only fires once the animation is completed
                if (options.changeText == 1) {
                    $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please take care to format your code correctly. It makes it much easier for you, and others, to read.

Comment: can u make fiddle it will be helpful .

Comment: jsfiddle.net fiddle it

Comment: sorry a little bit messy in my coding

Comment: @Tushar Gupta already edited

Comment: @Vivek Vikranth already edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to hide the `div` when you click on a button, you should make it the `document` when clicked to hide. Try something like this.

`$(".hide_show").click(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); $(this).fadeToggle(1000);}); $(document).click(function() { $(".hide_show).fadeOut(1000); });`

use `event.stopPropagation();` to stop the document event to trigger `.hide_show` class. May be that will help you.

Comment: thanks..sorry,im new in programming..where should i put??
and how to use event.stopPropagation();

Comment: sorry. okay, if you have two `div`s with class `.click_toggle` and `toggle_div`, and you want to hide and show `.toggle_div` when you click on `click_toggle`. you should apply a `jquery` like this `$(".click_toggle").click(function() { $(".toggle_div").toggle(); });` and now you want to hide the `toggle_dive` when you click outside of it' you should apply another code like this `$(document).click(function() { $(".toggle_div").hide(); });` if you don't want the document even to trigger `.click_toggle` event, you should make it `$(".click_toggle").click(function(e) ( e.stopPropagation();

Comment: instead of `$(".click_toggle").click(function() { $(".toggle_div").toggle(); });` because it may cause Js malfunctioning if you didn't add the `e.stopPropagation();`. Take note. `event` is same as `e`.

Comment: thanks for your help..it works..but when i click outside of it my div is not hiding but it its disable or gone..
i just want my div to slide up when i click other button..

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery,

```
$("your_other_button").on('click', function() {
      $("your_div_to_hide").hide();
});
```

Comment: where can i write this?

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

```
$("other_button").on('click', function() {
    $("div_to_hide").toggle();
});
```

Comment: you can add this before the html body ends in a script tag